# C++ constexpr list with size in its type

Tags: c++, list

I am trying to develop a constexpr, functional list data structure in C++. I am also trying to take advantage of recursive structure of the cons list approach. I had couple of attempts and for those, you can see my past questions. For now, I have settled on to the idea of making the size a part of type, ie. `List. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
struct list {
    public:

    constexpr list(const T& head, const list<T, N-1> &tail)
    :_length{N}, _head{head}, _tail{tail}
    {}

    const unsigned int _length;
    const T _head;
    const list<T, N-1> _tail;
};

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
constexpr auto head(const list<T, N> &li) {
    return li._head;
}

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
constexpr auto tail(const list<T, N> &li) {
    return li._tail;
}

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
constexpr auto prepend(const T &new_head, const list<T, N> &li){
    return list<T, N + 1>{new_head,
                          list<T, N>{head(li), tail(li)}};
}

template <typename T>
struct list<T, 0>
{
    constexpr static const bool nil = true;
};

template <typename T>
using nil = list<T, 0>;

template <typename Functor, typename T, unsigned int N>
constexpr auto fmap(Functor f, const list<T, N> &li) {
    if constexpr(N == 0)
        return nil<T>{};
    else
        return list{f(head(li)), fmap(f, tail(li))};
}

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, const list<T, N> &li) {
    if constexpr(N == 0)
        return str;
    else{
        str << head(li) << ' ' << tail(li);
        return str;
    }
}

int main(){
    constexpr auto f = [](int x){ return x * x; };

    constexpr list<char, 2> p2{'U', list<char, 1>{'S', nil<char>{}}};
    constexpr auto p3 = prepend('S', p2);

    constexpr list<int, 2> i1{1, list<int, 1>{2, nil<int>{}}};
    constexpr auto i2 = fmap(f, i1);

    std::cout << p3;
}
```

Some of it works to some extent. `fmap` is the one keeping my program from compiling. I get the error

> prog.cc:47:16: error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'list'
>           return list{f(head(li)), fmap(f, tail(li))};
>
> prog.cc:47:34: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'fmap<(lambda at prog.cc:61:24), int, 1>' requested here
>           return list{f(head(li)), fmap(f, tail(li))};
>
> prog.cc:67:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'fmap<(lambda at prog.cc:61:24), int, 2>' requested here
>       constexpr auto i2 = fmap(f, i1);
>
> prog.cc:8:15: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'N'
>       constexpr list(const T& head, const list &tail)

and similar. I am lost here, what is the cause of this error? It seems like compiler deduced the argument `N` correctly, as it says `N=2`. I feel like I need to add some base cases related to lists of size zero but could not figure it out.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return list<T, N>{ f(head(li)), fmap(f, tail(li)) }`?

Comment: In function `prepend()` why don't you simply return `list<T, N + 1>{new_head, li}`? What am I missing?

Comment: @MariusBancila which is even stranger taken into account `list` lacks move-ctor.

Comment: Why do you need `_length` at all, it's template parameter.

Comment: @MariusBancila sorry, that was a mistake from a past implementation and I forgot to change there. For _length, I think it is just habitual. Yeah, I could remove it.

Comment: @bipli Can we chat on any place for a moment, I want to ask couple of things about move-ctors. Since this is a constexpr list, I don't know if move makes sense and it confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo: missing type specifiers when using template struct list. Bellow should work

```
template <typename Functor, typename T, unsigned int N>
constexpr auto fmap(Functor f, const list<T, N> &li) {
    if constexpr(N == 0)
        return nil<T>{};
    else 
        return list<T, N-1>{f(head(li)), fmap(f, tail(li))};
}
```

Comment: I though compiler could deduce it from the arguments but I guess recursive use of `fmap` trips its mind.

Comment: @meguli No, you are not right. Compiler can not deduce template parameters since when a template parameter is used only in a nondeduced context (the case for Functor in your function) it's not taken into consideration for template argument deduction

Comment: I didn't call `fmap` with explicit templates in the main, so compiler was able to deduce the type of `f` and `li` in the beginning, right? How is `f` nondeduced then? I am looking at type-deduction related sources to understand what's really going on but would be great if you can edit your answer by giving a simple to understand explanation for why it failed in the first place.